# Add Power-law and exponential fit based on chi square error minimization to my PDF

Tags: python, curve-fitting, exponential, chi-squared

Hello as the title suggests I have been trying to add an exponential and power law fit to my PDF.
As shown in this picture:
[image]

The code i am using produces the underlying graph:
[image]

The code is this one:

```
   a11=[9.76032106e-02, 6.73754187e-02, 3.20683249e-02, 2.21788509e-02,
       2.70850237e-02, 9.90377323e-03, 2.11573411e-02, 8.46232347e-03,
       8.49027869e-03, 7.33997745e-03, 5.71819070e-03, 4.62720448e-03,
       4.11562884e-03, 3.20064313e-03, 2.66192941e-03, 1.69116510e-03,
       1.94355212e-03, 2.55224949e-03, 1.23822395e-03, 5.29618250e-04,
       4.03769641e-04, 3.96865740e-04, 3.38530868e-04, 2.04124701e-04,
       1.63913557e-04, 2.04486864e-04, 1.82216592e-04, 1.34708400e-04,
       9.24289261e-05, 9.55074181e-05, 8.13695322e-05, 5.15610541e-05,
       4.15425149e-05, 4.68101099e-05, 3.33696885e-05, 1.61893058e-05,
       9.61743970e-06, 1.17314090e-05, 6.65239507e-06]

b11=[3.97213201e+00, 4.77600082e+00, 5.74255432e+00, 6.90471618e+00,
       8.30207306e+00, 9.98222306e+00, 1.20023970e+01, 1.44314081e+01,
       1.73519956e+01, 2.08636432e+01, 2.50859682e+01, 3.01627952e+01,
       3.62670562e+01, 4.36066802e+01, 5.24316764e+01, 6.30426504e+01,
       7.58010432e+01, 9.11414433e+01, 1.09586390e+02, 1.31764173e+02,
       1.58430233e+02, 1.90492894e+02, 2.29044305e+02, 2.75397642e+02,
       3.31131836e+02, 3.98145358e+02, 4.78720886e+02, 5.75603061e+02,
       6.92091976e+02, 8.32155588e+02, 1.00056488e+03, 1.20305636e+03,
       1.44652749e+03, 1.73927162e+03, 2.09126048e+03, 2.51448384e+03,
       3.02335795e+03, 3.63521656e+03, 4.37090138e+03]
                                                      
    plt.plot(b11,a11, 'ro')
    plt.yscale("log")
    plt.xscale("log")
    
    plt.show()
```

I would like to add to the underlying graph a power law fit at smaller time and an exponential fit for loner times  based on chi square error minimization method.

The data for the x axis saved in csv form:

The data for the x axis:

Comment: There is no question in your post. What is your problem ?

Comment: @JJacquelin My bad.. i forgot to add the question. I have updated my question! Thanks

Comment: What about just fitting `(a * x**( -b ) + c ) * exp( -d * x )` I'd say that would fit the data well.

Comment: @Jokerp. Would you mind post the data. Deriving it from the picture isn't accurate enough.

Comment: Does the model require exponential or would a second power-law with different slope suffice?

Comment: @JJacquelin I have removed the uncesaary code and only posted tha data needed to plot tha final figure

Comment: @mikuszefski Yes the truth is that both a power law and an exponential are needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments, I think you can couple the power law and the exponential via a constant term. Alternatively, the data look like it can be fitted by two power laws. Although the comments suggest that there is truly an exponential behavior. Anyhow, I show both approaches here. In both cases I try to avoid any type of piece-wise definition. This also ensures $C^infty$.

In the first approach we have `a * x**( -b )` for small `x` and `a1 * exp( -d * x )` for large `x`. The idea is to choose an `c` such that the power law is much bigger than `c` for the required small `x` but significantly smaller otherwise.
This allows for the function mentioned in my comment, namely `( a * x**( -b ) + c  ) * exp( -d * x )` . One may consider `c` as an transition parameter.

In the alternative approaches, I am taking two power-laws. There are, hence, two regions, In the first one function one is smaller, in the second, the second is smaller. As I always want the smaller function I make inverse summation, i.e., `f = 1 / ( 1 / f1 + 1 / f2 )`. As can be seen in the code below, I add an additional parameter ( technically in ] 0, infty [ ). This parameter controls the smoothness of the transition.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

data = np.loadtxt( "7jyRi.txt", delimiter=',' )

#### p-e: power and exponential coupled via a small constant term
def func_log( x, a, b, c, d ):
    return np.log10( ( a * x**( -b ) + c ) * np.exp( -d * x ) )

guess = [.1, .8, 0.01, .005 ]
testx = np.logspace( 0, 3, 150 )
testy = np.fromiter( ( 10**func_log( x, *guess ) for x in testx ), np.float )
sol, _ = curve_fit( func_log, data[ ::, 0 ], np.log10( data[::,1] ), p0=guess )
fity = np.fromiter( ( 10**func_log( x, *sol ) for x in testx ), np.float )

#### p-p: alternatively using two power laws
def double_power_log( x, a, b, c, d, k ):
    s1 = ( a * x**( -b ) )**k
    s2 = ( c * x**( -d ) )**k
    out = 1.0 / ( 1.0 / s1 + 1.0 / s2 )**( 1.0 / k )
    return np.log10( out )

aguess = [.1, .8, 1e7, 4, 1 ]
atesty = np.fromiter( ( 10**double_power_log( x, *aguess ) for x in testx ), np.float )
asol, _ = curve_fit( double_power_log, data[ ::, 0 ], np.log10( data[ ::, 1 ] ), p0=aguess )
afity = np.fromiter( ( 10**double_power_log( x, *asol ) for x in testx ), np.float )

#### plotting
fig = mp.figure( figsize=( 10, 8 ) )
ax = fig.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1 )
ax.plot( data[::,0], data[::,1] ,ls='', marker='o', label="data" )
ax.plot( testx, testy ,ls=':', label="guess p-e" )
ax.plot( testx, atesty ,ls=':',label="guess p-p" )
ax.plot( testx, fity ,ls='-',label="fit p-e: {}".format( sol ) )
ax.plot( testx, afity ,ls='-', label="fit p-p: {}".format( asol ) )
ax.set_xscale( "log" )
ax.set_yscale( "log" )
ax.set_xlim( [ 5e-1, 2e3 ] )
ax.set_ylim( [ 1e-5, 2e-1 ] )
ax.legend( loc=0 )
mp.show()
```

The results look like

[image: Fit and alternative approach]

Answer (score 0):

For completeness I'd like to add a solution with a piece-wise definition. As I want the function continuous and differentiable, the parameters of the exponential law are not completely free. With `f = a * x**(-b)` and `g = alpha * exp( -beta * x )` and a transition at `x0` I choose `( a, b, x0 )` as free parameters. From this `alpha` and `beta` follow. The equations have no easy solution though, such that this itself requires a minimization.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as mp
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.special import lambertw

data = np.loadtxt( "7jyRi.txt", delimiter=',' )

def pwl( x, a, b):
    return a * x**( -b )

def expl( x, a, b ):
    return a * np.exp( -b * x )

def alpha_fun(alpha, a, b, x0):
    out = alpha - pwl( x0, a, b ) * expl(1, 1, lambertw( pwl( x0, -a * b/ alpha, b ) ) )
    return 1e10 * np.abs( out )**2

def p_w( v, a,b, alpha, beta, x0 ):
    if v < x0:
        out = pwl( v, a, b )
    else:
        out = expl( v, alpha, beta )
    return np.log10( out )


def alpha_beta( x, a, b, x0 ):
    """
    continuous and differentiable define alpha and beta
    free parameter is the point where I connect
    """
    sol = minimize(alpha_fun, .005, args=( a, b, x0 ) )### attention, strongly depends on starting guess, i.e might be a catastrophic fail
    alpha = sol.x[0]
    # ~print alpha
    beta = np.real( -lambertw( pwl( x0, -a * b/ alpha, b ) )/ x0 )
    ### 
    if isinstance( x, ( np.ndarray, list, tuple ) ):
        out = list()
        for v in x:
            out.append( p_w( v, a, b, alpha, beta, x0 ) )
    else:
        out = p_w( v, a, b, alpha, beta, x0 )
    return out

sol,_ = curve_fit( alpha_beta, data[ ::, 0 ], np.log10( data[ ::, 1 ] ), p0=[ .1, .8, 70. ] )

alpha0 = minimize(alpha_fun, .005, args=tuple(sol ) ).x[0]
beta0 = np.real( -lambertw( pwl( sol[2], -sol[0] * sol[1]/ alpha0, sol[1] ) )/ sol[2] )

xl = np.logspace(0,3,100)
yl = alpha_beta( xl, *sol )

pl = pwl( xl, sol[0], sol[1] )
el = expl( xl, alpha0, beta0 )
#### plotting
fig = mp.figure( figsize=( 10, 8 ) )
ax = fig.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1 )
ax.plot( data[::,0], data[::,1] ,ls='', marker='o', label="data" )
ax.plot( xl, pl ,ls=':', label="p" )
ax.plot( xl, el ,ls=':', label="{:0.3e} exp(-{:0.3e} x)".format(alpha0, beta0) )
ax.plot( xl, [10**y for y in yl] ,ls='-', label="sol: {}".format(sol) )

ax.axvline(sol[-1], color='k', ls=':')
ax.set_xscale( "log" )
ax.set_yscale( "log" )
ax.set_xlim( [ 5e-1, 2e3 ] )
ax.set_ylim( [ 1e-5, 2e-1 ] )
ax.legend( loc=0 )
mp.show()
```

Eventually providing

[image: Piecewise]

Comment: Could you please add a few comments here and there so I can apply this to other distributions? Thanks!